# In email recognizing pattern for entity in ibm watson what is the term {2, } indicates here?

Tags: regex, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

This is the pattern for recognizing an email value for the entity in IBM Watson.

```
\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}\b
```

Can you please elaborate it why below terms are used here:

```
\b
{2, }
```

Comment: Are you referring to the SAMPLE pattern shown here? https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-entities#entities-patterns

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a regex question.

`\b` indicates word boundaries

`{2,}` means repeat the previous at least twice. In your case the previous being any upper and lower case alphabetic characters.